# How to generate descriptive text based on a key-value property list using Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of properties, name:value style. The name and value could be anything. I would like to generate gramatically correct descriptive text that considers the entire set of name:value pairs. The generator should be smart enough to recognize the type of the property based on the property name and generate appropriate text.

For example:

```
name:John
age: 26
height:6ft 2inches
eyecolor: blue
profession: cowboy
Expected output - something along the lines of:
John is a cowboy, aged 26. His height is 6ft 2 inches and he has blue eyes.

ApplicationName: Goole maps
Developer: Google
Usage: Geo navigation
available on: desktop, notebook, tablet, mobile phones
competition: Apple, Facebook, Microsoft
Expected output:
Google Maps is a geo navigation app developed by Google. It is available on desktops, notebooks,tablets and mobile phones. it's main competitors are Apple, Yahoo and Facebook maps.
```

How should I approach this problem? Would this be a machine learning problem? Or can I implement this using plain NLP without the need for ML? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: If the set of keys is known you can hard code the different configurations. If not, I see two initial approaches. The first way would require a large labeled dataset for learning how different keys are used in relation to each other. The second approach would be to forget about the keys and just use a even larger learning dataset to learn how these types of words can be used in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the name and value could be anything, this is quite a difficult problem. Especially compounded by the fact that the output sentences seem to be quite free, which opens a whole can of worms in terms of style.

The best approach I can think of is to build a dataset of properties and target sentences. Then build a network such that, based on the input pairs of key and values, generate a sequence of text as the appropriate caption.

The key (no pun intended) would be joining the key and value representations in such a way that the pair relationship is retained which would benefit the generation work later on - as opposed to pumping the entire property list as-is into the network

Comment: How about if I simplify the problem and say that I will only have 1 type of name value pairs list? name, age, height, eyecolor, profession? I can easily generate fixed descriptive text by having the text as xsl templates with placeholders for the values, key/values as XML and using xpath and xslt to combine the template and the data. Can I get better results using NLP and ML?

Comment: As with all machine learning problems, we have to focus on the target outcome we want. In this case, if you limit the pair types, the best solution would be effectively having templates. 

When you say "better" what do you mean by that?